# Converting .mov to file compatible with my Sony PlayStation 3 without losing quality

Tags: conversion, hd-video

I read the latest post on Canonical Design on a film titled "Press Pause Play" here:
http://design.canonical.com/2011/11/when-humans-make-stuff-we-tend-to-make-interesting-things/

I have been on the official website and downloaded the 1080p version of the film, the only available format to download is .MOV which is not compatible to play on the PlayStation 3.

How would I convert the file to something playable on the PlayStation without losing the 1080p HD video quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose quality (unavoidable, any time you transcode you lose quality), although it might not be noticeable. You can use a program such as handbrake (downloadable from their PPA, see http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php )

It no longer has a preset for PS3, but a quick search found these instructions.

### Adding PS3 template to handbrake (from [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1350522))

1. Download [the template](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=139201&d=1260377807) and rename it to PS3.plist
2. Open Handbrake, go to bottom left corner, click on 'Options' then 'Import' and choose PS3.plist

### Transcode the video

1. Load the source video into Handbrake
2. Select the PS3 template from the right pane
3. Click transcode and wait for the process to finish

Comment: Note, I don't have a PS3 to test and I am currently on my netbook, but those instructions should be enough. I also was unable to verify the settings on that template (to verify it was transcoding to 1080P video)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's currently encoding now but will take a few hours so I will update and accept your answer if all goes well :)

Comment: The file was over 4gb in size until after I transcoded it, now it is 1.3gb but it plays fine and I don't notice a lack of quality visually. I can now play the movie on my PlayStation 3 and now have the know how for future reference.. Thank you :)